# Dynamically add 'value' attribute to option tag with D3

Tags: javascript, html, d3.js

I'd like to populate my option tags' `value` attributes dynamically with the same text used to set the text value.  Below is my current code.

HTML:

```html
<script src="http://d3js.org/d3.v3.min.js" charset="utf-8"></script>
<div id="x_axis">x axis: </div>
```

JavaScript:

```js
d3.csv('data/3457/CLVF_l3e.csv', function(error, data){
  var headers = d3.keys(data[0]);

  var xAxis = d3.select("#x_axis")
    .append("select")
    .selectAll("option")
      .data(headers)
    .enter().append("option")
      .text(String);
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you ask for is not necessary. If you produce the HTML:

```
<select>
  <option>A</option>
  <option>B</option>
</select>
```

directly or via D3—without `value="…"` attributes on the option elements—then the value for each option that will be submitted with the form (and accessible via the `.value` property of the option element, and set as the `.value` property of the select element) *is* the text of the option. Using `getAttribute()` will (properly) not show this value, but accessing the property will.

### Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/dMr6A/2/

However, in general in D3.js to set an attribute to a value you would use the [`selection.attr` method](https://github.com/mbostock/d3/wiki/Selections#wiki-attr):

```
.enter().append("option")
  .text(String)
  .attr('value',String);
```

### Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/dMr6A/1/

Comment: I've noticed that .text(TxtString).attr('value',String) causes value attribute to disappear; both if TxtString == String, and if not.

Comment: @sdbbs I think you must be seeing some other problem masquerading as that. If you click on the second demo above, and then inspect the DOM produced for the select, the `.outerHTML` (from Chrome) is: `<select><option value=""></option><option value="a">a</option><option value="b">b</option><option value="c">c</option></select>`.